# Magento custom module new order email not showing order items

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to send email programmaticaly with order items grid using

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

but its not working.it is blank. But

```
{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

show customer name properly.also shipping address ,billing address,payment method etc. are showing properly

what is missing?

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you find out why this was happening? I'm having the same issue on the same mage version

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module, you must set all required params.

```
...
$mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
$mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
$mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this, /* This is just order object. Please check if this object is null or not. */
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
...
```

Comment: params are proper..thats why i am geting other order details like shipping adddress ,payment method,customer name etc..

Comment: {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}. Yeah. If that params are proper, you can get all of them( billing, shipping... ) correctly.

Comment: everything else displaying properly except order item table.

Comment: Please check your layout xml : frontend/default/[Your Theme]/layout/sales.xml. In this file, there is layout configuration : <sales_email_order_items>...</sales_email_order_items>